# Disabling mod_mime_magic module per directory

Tags: apache-2.2

I would like to be able to disable the Apache module `mime_magic` in a particular directory (and its children). I've searched around, and there seem to be special one-off flags you can set to disable some modules (PHP, deflate, etc), but nothing general (or specific to `mime_magic`.

Is there a way to disable `mime_magic` in one directory? There's a known issue with it causing issues serving BAM files with [JBrowse](http://gmod.org/wiki/JBrowse_Configuration_Guide#Apache_Configuration_Note), and the recommended workaround is to disable `mime_magic`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The module (like all modules) is enabled server-wide.  The only available configuration directive is [MimeMagicFile](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime_magic.html#mimemagicfile), which can be set at the server or virtual host level.  So if you wanted to disable it for a specific virtual host, I suppose you could set `MimeMagicFile /dev/null` in that vhost.  But there doesn't seem to be any way of disabling it for a specific directory.

Comment: Thanks, that was the conclusion I came to as well. `MimeMagicFile` seems to work.